# How to create a Kotlin Decimal Formatter

Tags: kotlin, decimalformat, numberformatter

I would like to create a decimal formatter that would display up to 2 decimal digits, with a given separator.

For example with separator `","`

```
input -> output
3.0   -> "3"
3.1   -> "3,1"
3.14  -> "3,14"
3.141 -> "3,14"
3.149 -> "3,15"
```

I would like to do this in Kotlin, I guess I must use `DecimalFormat` but don't understand how to do so. Could you please help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not meant for converting code from one language to another

Comment: I think the question is fine, but it definitely needs improvements, primarily showing what they have tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Disagree with close vote. It’s not like the OP is asking for a big block of code to be converted or is even asking about syntax at all. The Swift code shown is just a way of illustrating the problem they’re trying to solve. And the problem they’re solving is so small that it would not be helpful to people trying to answer what they tried already. There’s no partial solution that would be helpful to start from.

Comment: @LeoDabus no need to be so pedantic. They were using Swift as an example of the kind of input/output expected. And not even knowing that specific library it's easy to guess what kind of function they are looking for

Comment: This question is fine.  [An attempt to solve is not required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/208273) (cc @undermark5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below was tested against all your examples and seemed to work well:

```
val locale = Locale("en", "UK")
val symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(locale)
symbols.decimalSeparator = ','
val pattern = "#.##"
val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols)
val format = decimalFormat.format(3.14)
println(format)  //3,14
```

To set a specific separator in your DecimalFormat, you can use [setDecimalSeparator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decimalformatsymbols-setdecimalseparator-method-in-java-with-examples/).

Pay attention to the pattern as # means:

> A digit, leading zeroes are omitted

You can obviously change the locale to your fitting.

More information [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html#creating-a-decimalformat).

Comment: As far as I understand, using the constructor of `DecimalFormat` is discouraged by the documentation: `In general, do not call the DecimalFormat constructors directly, since the NumberFormat factory methods may return subclasses other than DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

You indeed might use `java.text.NumberFormat` to achieve your goal. The following should work is quite close to your example Swift code.

```kotlin
// you can change the separators by providing a Locale
val nf = java.text.NumberFormat
    .getInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMAN)
nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
   
// you may want to change the rounding mode
nf.roundingMode = java.math.RoundingMode.DOWN
    
println(nf.format(0)) // 0
println(nf.format(1)) // 1
println(nf.format(1.2)) // 1,2
println(nf.format(1.23)) // 1,23
println(nf.format(1.234)) // 1,23
println(nf.format(12.345)) // 12,34
```