# How to add a double to two digits after the dot? Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I post value to my api. It accepts double with two decimals after dot such as 100.00 or 500.00. One decimals such as 50.0 is not accepted. How can I convert string to double with two decimals after dot?

What I tried is `val price= String.format("%.2f",priceInput.value!!.toDouble()).toDouble` but it gives 100.0 instead of 100.00 because toDouble eliminate unnecessary decimals.

Comment: There really is no difference between the Double 100.0 and 100.00 or 100.000. Doubles don't hold any information about leading zeroes or trailing zeroes behind the decimal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055153/how-to-create-a-kotlin-decimal-formatter

Comment: lvo I know that but I can't change api. It only accepts like `100.00`.

Comment: Ken Wolf, your link shows to create a string from double input, but I to need create a double from string.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have different inputs:

```
val a = "23.2443"
val b = "23"    
val c = "23.244.3.ws"
```

With following example:

```
println(String.format("%.2f", (a.toDoubleOrNull()) ?: 0.0))
println(String.format("%.2f", (b.toDoubleOrNull()) ?: 0.0))
println(String.format("%.2f", (c.toDoubleOrNull()) ?: 0.0))
```

You get:

```
23.24
23.00
0.00
```

Comment: It gives a string, not a double. The reason what I need is double is api accepts double, not string.

Comment: Double comes with only one digit after dot, not two (in case of zeros) What is the API?